# Python Comparing Two Data Frames with Group By

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have two data frames. For example:

```
df1:
ID Value1 Country Value2 Desc Value3
AA 5.442  US       6.32  desc1 7.02   
BB 7.442  IN       2.32  desc2 5.02
CC 3.442  JP       4.32  desc3 2.02
DD 2.442  AU       5.32  desc4 6.02

df2:
ID Value1 Country Value2 Desc Value3
AA 5.3    US       5.12  desc1 7.02   
BB 7.12   UK       1.32  desc2 5.02
CC 3.542  JP       2.12  desc3 2.02
DD 2.4    AU       5.82  desc4 6.02
```

I need to compare these two data frames (suppose ID is the index), I need to compare other columns like "Value1", "Country" and so on. If the column is a numeric value, I need to find difference of it and need to check whether it exceeds a tolerance limit (for example, if it reaches > 10%), I need to mark that record as a difference and write it to a new data frame with what column got changed and how much got changed, something like:

```
ID Column_Name df1_value df2_value difference
AA Value1      5.442     5.3       0.142  
BB Country     IN        UK        <blank>
```

I have tried concatenating two data frames and tried grouping by ID, but not sure how to proceed after that.

```
concat_df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=0)
grouped = concat_df.groupby('ID')
```

Inside the grouped data frames, I get two rows for each ID, I am not sure how to check each column value based on its type. If type is numeric, I need to find differences, and if type is string I need to do an `equals` compare.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple:

```
concat_df['diff12'] = (concat_df['v1'] - concat_df['v2']) / concat_df['v2']
concat_df['diff34'] = (concat_df['v3'] - concat_df['v4']) / concat_df['v4']
mask = (concat_df['diff12'] > 0.10) | (concat_df['diff34'] > 0.10)
concat_df = concat_df[mask]
```

You can loop over all the columns you want to check.  You may need to add a MultiIndex level when you do `pd.concat` if you have duplicate column names as in your example.

Comment: Thanks for the response , My both dataframes has same structure(like no. of columns and column names), also i have given only 4 columns in this example , there are around 30+ odd columns in my dataframes , I need to loop over each column and identify is type and do a comparison based on the type. Is there something i could do with lambda or any other solution which is generic

Comment: @PrabakaranC: You can write a loop, create N "diff" columns, and then use `.any(axis=0)` to check them all at the end.

Comment: Sorry i am just learning python, could you please elaborate more on this or share some examples

Comment: @PrabakaranC: `for column in concat_df.columns:` and then you fill in the loop body with the code in my answer, slightly adjusted to use the correct column names.